# Lazy-Loading not working on image slider plugin (WordPress, PHP, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, lazy-loading

I would appreciate some help with my lazy loading scripts. For reasons that escape me, images within the plugin `Master Slider` don't get lazy loaded.

My `JavaScript` searches for all images with a `data-src` attribute. If an image has the attribute, it exchanges it with a regular `src` attribute and the image loads. If no `data-src` is present, the image is left alone.

Prior to this, I intended for a `PHP` script to get all images and exchange `src` with `data-src`, so the images can't load with the page.

It works on everything but the image slider. It's implemented via the plugin `Master Slider`.

I think the problem has to be within the `PHP`, since the slider does load - just not lazily. All `src` attributes work, which means `JavaScript` left the slider alone.

Does anyone have an idea why this is?

**PHP:**

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_lazyload_content_images' );
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'my_lazyload_content_images' );
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'my_lazyload_attachments', 10, 2 );

// Replace the image attributes in Post/Page Content
function my_lazyload_content_images( $content ) {

  //-- Change src/srcset to data attributes.
  $content = preg_replace( '/(<img.+)(src)/Ui', '$1data-$2', $content );
  $content = preg_replace( '/(<img.+)(srcset)/Ui', '$1data-$2', $content );

  //-- Add .lazy-load class to each image that already has a class.
  $content = preg_replace('/<img(.*?)class=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)>/i', '<img$1class="$2 lazy-load"$3>', $content);

  //-- Add .lazy-load class to each image that doesn't already have a class.
  $content = preg_replace('/<img((.(?!class=))*)\/?>/i', '<img class="lazy-load"$1>', $content);

  return $content;
}

// Replace the image attributes in Post Listing, Related Posts, etc.
function my_lazyload_attachments( $atts, $attachment ) {
  $atts['data-src'] = $atts['src'];
  unset( $atts['src'] );
  
  if( isset( $atts['srcset'] ) ) {
    $atts['data-srcset'] = $atts['srcset'];
    unset( $atts['srcset'] );
  }

  return $atts;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
let lazyImgs = document.querySelectorAll("img[data-src]");

function lazyLoad(lazyImgs) {
  const imgOptions = {
    threshold: 0.25,
    rootMargin: "0%",
  };

  const imgObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, imgObserver) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
        // get currently intersecting picture element and its children (source, img)
        let lazyImage = entry.target;

        // check if the element really has the attribute data-src, which we're using for lazy loading
        // if it doesn't leave the image alone
        if (lazyImage.hasAttribute("data-src")) {
          // exchange the src
          lazyImage.src = lazyImage.dataset.src;

          // also exchange the src, if the image has one
          if (lazyImage.srcset) {
            lazyImage.srcset = lazyImage.dataset.srcset;
          }
        } else {
          return false;
        }

        lazyImage.classList.add('is-loaded');

        // end observation of image once it's loaded :)
        imgObserver.unobserve(lazyImage);
      } // end is intersecting
    });
  }, imgOptions);

  // loop through all images and observe every single one
  lazyImgs.forEach((lazyImg) => {
    imgObserver.observe(lazyImg);
  });
} // end lazyLoad();

lazyLoad(lazyImgs);


And the CSS: 

.lazy-load {
  transition: opacity .15s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.lazy-load.is-loaded {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not just using the default html5 lazy loading?

```
<img src="_path_to_image_" loading="lazy">
```

https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/